# how do i block top links from being index magento2 using robot text

Tags: header, toplinks

Google seems to be indexing Wishlist - Add to Cart, My Account” and “Log In/Log Out” links. is there any ways to have something in robot text to block it?

add to cart seem to be appearing on google site link

Answer (score 1):

A no follow link is created with the nofollow link HTML tag, which looks like this:

```
<a href=”http://www.website.com/” rel=”nofollow”>Link Text</a>
```

The nofollow tag is basically a notice sign for search engines saying “don’t count this.”